# How could i refresh Android Fragment/s content onBack Press?

Tags: android-fragments

How could i refresh Fragment/s content onBack Press ?

```
FragmentManager back = getFragmentManager();
back.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.left, new ArticleFragment()).commit();
back.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.middle, new LocationFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

refresh the contents of a fragment, 
you could keep a reference to the fragment, and call a public refresh() method in that fragment.
when you create the tab fragment, 
like the PupulareFragment, use the pupulareFragment instance variable to store the fragment. So it is available in the refresh button onClick method.

This way you are not replacing/creating any new fragments when refreshing. So going back to tabActivity after going to de article details activity, would probably work fine aswell.

Example:

```
public class ArticleTabFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity{
     private PopulareFragment populareFragment;
     private RecomandateFragment recomandateFragment;

     <the code...>

     private void bindView(){
              Button btn_refresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_refresh);

              btn_refresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               public void onClick(View v) {
                    String current_tab = mTabHost.getCurrentTabTag(); 
                    if(current_tab.contains("POPULARE")){
                             populareFragment.refresh();
                    } 
                    else if(current_tab.contains("RECOMANDATE")){
                          recomandateFragment.refresh();
                    } 
              });
     }



   }

   public class PopulareFragment extends Fragment{  

     public void refresh(){
              <refresh the contents of the fragment>
     }

   }
```